# How to make the code simple in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There many repeated code in Code A, I hope to make it simply, but Code B doesn't work, how can I fix it? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
aMDetail?.findByDeviceDef<BluetoothDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
aMDetail?.findByDeviceDef<WiFiDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
aMDetail?.findByDeviceDef<ScreenDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
```

**Code B**

```
with(aMDetail?){
    findByDeviceDef<BluetoothDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
    findByDeviceDef<WiFiDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
    findByDeviceDef<ScreenDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using run, with, let, also and apply. Based on your convenience Please go through this link for more details [Mastering Kotlin standard functions: run, with, let, also and apply](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

As @veritas1 answered and @EpicPandaForce commented, there may have a couple of approaches which can meet your needs, but each of them has some differences about how they pass the argument to the block and what the return values are, I write some code to indicate the differences:

```
class Test {
    fun a() {}

    fun b() {}

    fun c() {}
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test: Test? = Test()

    test?.apply {
        // `apply` passes the receiver as `this`
        a()
        b()
        c()
    }?.a() // works, because `apply` returns `this`

    test?.also {
        // `also` passes the receiver as `it`
        with(it) {
            a()
            b()
            c()
        }
    }?.a() // works, because `also` returns `this`

    test?.run {
        // `run` passes the receiver as `this`
        a()
        b()
        c()
    }?.a() // won't compile, because `run` returns the block's return value (Unit)

    test?.run {
        // `run` passes the receiver as `this`
        a()
        b()
        c()
        this
    }?.a() // works, because `run` returns the block returns `this`

    test?.let {
        with(it) {
            a()
            b()
            c()
        }
    }?.a() // won't compile, because `let` returns the block's return value (Unit)

    test?.let {
        with(it) {
            a()
            b()
            c()
        }
        it
    }?.a() // works, because the block returns `it`
}
```

This decision tree diagram from [Elye](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) can help you to choose the best method:

> [image: Decision]

As a sum up, the `run` are most suitable for you case, because you need `null checks` and send `this` as argument can make your code simpler:

```
test?.run {
    // `run` passes the receiver as `this`
    a()
    b()
    c()
}
```

**Original Answer**

Try with `let`:

```
aMDetail?.let {
    with(it) {
        findByDeviceDef<BluetoothDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
        findByDeviceDef<WiFiDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
        findByDeviceDef<ScreenDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `?.run {`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apply`. This will null check `aMDetail` then execute the code block in the context of `aMDetail`.

```
aMDetail?.apply {
    findByDeviceDef<BluetoothDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
    findByDeviceDef<WiFiDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
    findByDeviceDef<ScreenDef>()?.setDevice(mContext)
}
```